# Convert c# timestamps to javascript timestamps

Tags: javascript, c#, date, timestamp

I have a c# script in which I create a timestamp for current year, current month, current week and current day.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;

now = new DateTime(now.Year, 1, 1);
int yearDay = (int)(now.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;

now = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
int monthDay = (int)(now.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;

now = DateTime.UtcNow.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday);
int weekDay = (int)(now.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;

now = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day);
int toDay = (int)(now.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
```

Now I want to accomplished the same, but in javascript... i have gotten the year in place, but not sure how to get month, week and day.

```
var d = new Date();

// YEAR TIMESTAMP //
var thisYear = d.getUTCFullYear();
var y = Date.UTC(thisYear, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var yearDay = Math.floor(y / 1000);
```

Hope someone can help me in this matter and thanks in advance :-)

---

I have also gotten the month like this, but still needs to figure out how I get current day and week.

```
// MONTH TIMESTAMP //
var thisMonth = d.getUTCMonth();
var m = Date.UTC(thisYear, thisMonth, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var monthDay = Math.floor(m / 1000);

// C# toDay output: 1548979200
// C# weekDay output: 1548633600
```

Tried this for toDay but output is not the same as in C#:

```
// DAY TIMESTAMP //
var thisDay = d.getUTCDay();
var da = Date.UTC(thisYear, thisMonth, thisDay, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var toDay = Math.floor(da / 1000);

// output: 1549324800
```

Still hoping for help :-)

********* EDIT 2 ***********

OK, I finally got the day correct:

```
// DAY TIMESTAMP //
var da = Date.UTC(thisYear, thisMonth, thisDay, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var toDay = Math.floor(da / 1000);
```

Now whats left, is how I can get the week correct.

I have tried this:

```
// WEEK TIMESTAMP //
var w = Date.UTC(thisYear, thisMonth, d.setDate(d.getDate() - (d.getDay() || 7) + 1), 0, 0, 0, 0);
var weekDay = Math.floor(w / 1000);
```

This outputs a NaN. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: I would use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for this, if you want similar functionality out of the box.

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl I can not use moment.js thus the script will be run from a cloud script with any options to add other .js files :-/ Good solution though.

Comment: javascript date object has `getDay()`, `getMonth()` (note month is 0 indexed so you need to add 1 to it if you want feb to be 2) , `getDate()` (day of month)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked-out [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) reference on MDN?

Methods exists to retrieve this information.

```js
// Vanilla JS
var utcDate = new Date();
console.log({
  yearDay: utcDate.getUTCFullYear(),
  monthDay: utcDate.getUTCMonth(),
  weekDay: utcDate.getUTCDay(),
  toDay: utcDate.getUTCDate(),
  hour: utcDate.getUTCHours(),
  min: utcDate.getUTCMinutes(), 
  sec: utcDate.getUTCSeconds(),
  ms: utcDate.getUTCMilliseconds()
});

// Moment
var utcMoment = moment.utc();
console.log({
  yearDay: utcMoment.year(),
  monthDay: utcMoment.month(),
  weekDay: utcMoment.isoWeekday(),
  toDay: utcMoment.date(), // Day of month or utcMoment.dayOfYear(),
  hour: utcMoment.hours(),
  min: utcMoment.minutes(), 
  sec: utcMoment.seconds(),
  ms: utcMoment.milliseconds()
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

---

## Update

If you want to get the date of a particular day of the week, you can clone the date, calculate the diff in days, and add/subtract those number of days from the current date.

```js
const TimeUnit = {
  YEARS : {
    add : function(date, amount, utc) {
      if (utc) date.setUTCFullYear(date.getUTCFullYear() + amount);
      else date.setUTCFullYear(date.getUTCFullYear() + amount);
      return date;
    }
  },
  MONTHS : {
    add : function(date, amount, utc) {
      if (utc) date.setUTCMonth(date.getUTCMonth() + amount);
      else date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + amount);
      return date;
    }
  },
  DAYS : {
    add : function(date, amount, utc) {
      if (utc) date.setUTCDate(date.getUTCDate() + amount);
      else date.setDate(date.getDate() + amount);
      return date;
    }
  },
  HOURS : {
    add : function(date, amount, utc) {
      if (utc) date.setUTCHours(date.getUTCHours() + amount);
      else date.setHours(date.getHours() + amount);
      return date;
    }
  },
  MINUTES : {
    add : function(date, amount, utc) {
      if (utc) date.setUTCMinutes(date.getUTCMinutes() + amount);
      else date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + amount);
      return date;
    }
  },
  SECONDS : {
    add : function(date, amount, utc) {
      if (utc) date.setUTCSeconds(date.getUTCSeconds() + amount);
      else date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + amount);
      return date;
    }
  },
  MILLISECONDS : {
    add : function(date, amount, utc) {
      if (utc) date.setUTCMilliseconds(date.getUTCMilliseconds() + amount);
      else date.setMilliseconds(date.getMilliseconds() + amount);
      return date;
    }
  }
};

function addTime(date, timeUnit, amount, utc) {
  return timeUnit.add(date, amount, utc);
}

function getDateForCurrentWeek(date, dayOfWeek, utc) {
  var clone = new Date(date.getTime());
  var currentDay = (utc ? clone.getUTCDay() : clone.getDay()) || 7;
  var diff = dayOfWeek - currentDay + 1;
  return addTime(clone, TimeUnit.DAYS, diff, utc);
}

function printDate(targetEl, date, utc) {
  targetEl.value = JSON.stringify(utc ? {
    year: date.getUTCFullYear(),
    month: date.getUTCMonth() + 1,
    dayOfWeek: date.getUTCDay(),
    date: date.getUTCDate(),
    hour: date.getUTCHours(),
    min: date.getUTCMinutes(), 
    sec: date.getUTCSeconds(),
    ms: date.getUTCMilliseconds()
  } : {
    year: date.getFullYear(),
    month: date.getMonth() + 1,
    dayOfWeek: date.getDay(),
    date: date.getDate(),
    hour: date.getHours(),
    min: date.getMinutes(), 
    sec: date.getSeconds(),
    ms: date.getMilliseconds()
  }, null, 2);
}

function setDayOfWeekValue(selector, date, dayOfWeek, utc) {
  document.querySelector(selector).value = getDateForCurrentWeek(date, dayOfWeek, utc);
}

var utcDate = new Date();
setDayOfWeekValue('.day-sun', utcDate, 0, true);
setDayOfWeekValue('.day-mon', utcDate, 1, true);
setDayOfWeekValue('.day-tue', utcDate, 2, true);
setDayOfWeekValue('.day-wed', utcDate, 3, true);
setDayOfWeekValue('.day-thu', utcDate, 4, true);
setDayOfWeekValue('.day-fri', utcDate, 5, true);
setDayOfWeekValue('.day-sat', utcDate, 6, true);

// Test adding 1 unit to each date portion.
printDate(document.getElementById('result-1'), utcDate, true);
utcDate = addTime(utcDate, TimeUnit.YEARS, 1, true);
utcDate = addTime(utcDate, TimeUnit.MONTHS, 1, true);
utcDate = addTime(utcDate, TimeUnit.DAYS, 1, true);
utcDate = addTime(utcDate, TimeUnit.HOURS, 1, true);
utcDate = addTime(utcDate, TimeUnit.MINUTES, 1, true);
utcDate = addTime(utcDate, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 1, true);
utcDate = addTime(utcDate, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 1, true);
printDate(document.getElementById('result-2'), utcDate, true);
```

```css
.days-of-week .day-of-week {
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
}
.days-of-week label {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 3em;
}
.days-of-week input[class^="day-"] {
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 80vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="days-of-week">
  <div class="day-of-week"><label>Sun</label><input type="text" class="day-sun" /></div>
  <div class="day-of-week"><label>Mon</label><input type="text" class="day-mon" /></div>
  <div class="day-of-week"><label>Tue</label><input type="text" class="day-tue" /></div>
  <div class="day-of-week"><label>Wed</label><input type="text" class="day-wed" /></div>
  <div class="day-of-week"><label>Thu</label><input type="text" class="day-thu" /></div>
  <div class="day-of-week"><label>Fri</label><input type="text" class="day-fri" /></div>
  <div class="day-of-week"><label>Sat</label><input type="text" class="day-sat" /></div>
</div>

<textarea id="result-1" rows="12" cols="32"></textarea>
<textarea id="result-2" rows="12" cols="32"></textarea>
```

Comment: This is not for a html page and I cannot use moment.js or similar. see my edited post.

Comment: @Mansa I used vanilla JS in the response.

Comment: @ Mr. Polywhirl - Ahhh, didn't see that. That got me the current day, but now, all I am missing is how to get the current weeks first day (monday).

Comment: @Mansa—you can get the current week Monday (where weeks start on Monday) using *getDay*, e.g. `d.setDate(d.getDate() - (d.getDay() || 7) + 1)`.

Comment: @RobG - Not quite sure how to accomplish this. I have tried using your suggestion but with an NaN error to follow? (See my edited 2 post)

Comment: @Mansa You want the DATE for the Monday within the current week?

Answer (score 0):

To get the Monday at the start of the week, you can subtract the day number and add one. Sunday is 0, so to get the previous Monday change its day number to 7.

You are using the code incorrectly, `d.setDate(...)` returns the time value of the adjusted date, which is what you want. You don't need to do anything further. However, since you're using UTC values, here it is in your context.

I've changed the variable names to include UTC as a hint to their values. Also the "Date" methods return the day number in the month, the "Day" methods return the day number in the week.

```js
var d = new Date();
var utcYear = d.getUTCFullYear();
// Only year and month need to be set, missing values will default to minimums
var yearDay = Math.floor(Date.UTC(utcYear, 0) / 1000);

// MONTH TIMESTAMP //
var utcMonth = d.getUTCMonth();
var monthDay = Math.floor(Date.UTC(utcYear, utcMonth) / 1000);

// DAY TIMESTAMP // - changed "Day" to "Date"
var utcDate = d.getUTCDate();
var toDay = Math.floor(Date.UTC(utcYear, utcMonth, utcDate) / 1000);

// WEEK TIMESTAMP //
var w = new Date(Date.UTC(utcYear, utcMonth, utcDate));

// Set w to Monday at start of week
w.setUTCDate(w.getUTCDate() - (w.getUTCDay() || 7) + 1);

var weekDay = Math.floor(w / 1000);

console.log(yearDay, monthDay, toDay, weekDay);
```